# Redirect individual pages differently

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Most of my pages (pages 1,2,3) do not need to be parsed through PHP, however, pages 4 and 5 do.  For the pages that are parsed by PHP, I wish to rewrite the URL with up to (3) directories (page, g1, and g2).  Hopefully, the following table will make this more clear.

```
http://mydomain.com/          => http://mydomain.com/page1.html
http://mydomain.com/page1     => http://mydomain.com/page1.html
http://mydomain.com/page2/    => http://mydomain.com/page2.html
http://mydomain.com/page3     => http://mydomain.com/page3.html

http://mydomain.com/page4     => http://mydomain.com/main.php?page=page4
http://mydomain.com/page4/x/  => http://mydomain.com/main.php?page=page4&g1=x
http://mydomain.com/page4/x/y => http://mydomain.com/main.php?page=page4&g1=x&g2=y
http://mydomain.com/page5/    => http://mydomain.com/main.php?page=page5
```

I've made some progress on rewriting the URLs when parsed by PHP, however, am not sure how to handle determining how to differentiate between the ones that are redirected to their associated HTML file verse the ones that are redirected to index.php. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?page=$1&g1=$2&g2=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?page=$1&g2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to add is this line above the PHP `RewriteRule`s:

```
RewriteRule ^(page[123])/?$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Could you try that and see if it works?

Comment: I tried but it did not.  Since most of my pages need not be parsed, I would rather redirect all pages to their html associated page, and only if it is page4 or page5, redirect to main.php.  Also, I didn't say it, but page1,page2,etc were examples, and they wouldn't be numbered.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in your PHP script by using route.
For example, in `index.php`, you can write this

```
<?php
    $filename = $_REQUEST['page'];
    if(file_exists($filename.".html")){
        //display html
        require_once($filename.".html");
    }else if(file_exists($filename.".php")){
        //run your script
        require_once($filename.".php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but would rather not have PHP do work if it could be handled directory by Apache.